# How to ensure that all networking goes through my ssh proxy?

Tags: vpn, ssh

I have a network location set up to ssh tunnel to my server.  For now, just ssh -D type stuff.  This works fine.  I set up the tunnel from within my .screenrc.  In other words, "screen" is the trigger to connect to my proxy.  Before I type that I should not be able to go online.  However, lynx and ping go through without problems. tunnel or not.  This is disquieting.

How can I ensure all network traffic uses my Network settings, and not it's own?  The only way packets should be leaving is via my DynamicForward port.

EDIT:  The apple specificity comes with the Network settings, either accessed via System Preferences, or via networksetup.

OS X has both ipfw, and the application level firewall.

The appfirewall does not seem to stop things from going out.  It stops connections *to* the system.

Ipfw does take precedence over the application firewall, apparently.

My SOCKS5 proxy is set up on a port, and I then give  that  port to in a network Location as the SOCKS5 proxy.  This works fine.  As I see it, programs should not get a choice about using the proxy, and indeed, if I turn it off, browsers can not access the web.

Linux and *BSD's do not have the various ( quite nifty ) things that OSX has in this regard. For them, it would be ipchains and ipfw, respectively.

I think I'm missing something.  It should just work.

Comment: can you filter at the level of your router?

Comment: also, you may have a better chance with this question on unix.se, superuser, or serverfault.  It's not really apple specific so I'd actually propose that this is an off-topic/outside-scope question.  However, close voting is disabled due to the open bounty.

Comment: @calavera While I agree he might have better luck getting an answer on some of those sites and that there's nothing Apple *specific* about this question, the programs he mentions (with the exception of lynx) do ship with a Mac so it's not strictly off topic.

Comment: @Kyle: true enough, I mostly was worried about whether he'd get a good answer on here or not.  please see: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176/if-when-the-site-leaves-beta-will-there-be-an-option-to-migrate-questions

Comment: @calavera, I am using an Airport Express router.

Comment: The solution here is ipfw. No other way to trust the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `ssh` is running on `localhost` (or another machine on the local subnet), the easiest thing to do is to shut down your routes so that nothing can get outside.  `netstat -nr` will show you your current routes.  Mine looks like this:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use  Netif Expire
default            192.168.0.69       UGSc       93     4438    en1
```

`192.168.0.69` is my default route.  If I take that route out:  `route delete default 192.168.0.69` then I cannot get to any machine not wired to my network.  Once `screen` sets up your proxy, you should have access back.

Comment: Note that commands may be different in Linux/Unix.  OSX is a bit different in this area.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `man networksetup` to see if it could give you what you are looking for.

Comment: This is probably more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I knew about networksetup... tricky issue though, networksetup seems to be a command line interface to similar functions to the gui.  I'll have to run opensnoop to be sure, running strings implies that it is a level higher than the "kill switch", that route is.